# Is there an Arduino Simulator or Emulator that runs on OS X?

Tags: emulation, simulator, osx

Is there an Arduino Simulator or Emulator or cross-compiler to native Mac executable that runs directly under Mac OS X, and does **NOT** require a Windows or Linux VM or an active internet connection for running in the cloud?

There **are** previous questions here on similar topics, but they do not seem to address exactly this particular use case subset.

Comment: Is this not adequate? http://123d.circuits.io/

Answer (score 3):

I am using the [Wokwi Arduino simulator](https://wokwi.com) for a long time. It runs on all three platforms. Mobile, Windows OS, and macOS.
I have checked the working of the simulator in both Android and iPhone. Both give a good performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Arduino CodeBlocks](https://github.com/provideyourown/CodeBlocks-Arduino/) plug-in has an Arduino simulator. Be carefull when setting it up and use full paths, it's easy to mess up, but works beautifully once done.